Unable to hear audio from HDMI after Ubuntu upgrade to 24.04
I upgraded Ubuntu to version 24.04 from version~23.12 day before and now it seems audio is not working with HDMI selected  , this was working perfectly fine in the previous version.HDMI video is working perfectly fine.

I can see option to select  system speakers and HDMI in the sound
settings GUI.
-The system speakers are working when selected , however on switching
to HDMI , there is no sound , even though I can see the sound bar
move when clicking left/right speaker in the test speaker widget.
-I am trying to get HDMI audio to work since the system speaker quality is bad ,any help on this is appreciated

Laptop is Acer Nitro model
After seeing multiple threads for audio issues , I think it might have to do with the below showing under lshw
-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:b4324000-b4327fff

